# How to penalise negative weights in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm building a neural network with TensorFlow and I'm trying to implement a quadratic penalization to negative values in the weight matrix, i.e. P(W[i,j]) = W[i,j]^2 if W[i,j] < 0.

In summary, I initialized the weights, performed some operations, defined the main objective function to minimize, and defined this nonnegativity penalization as follows:

```
self.W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((input_dim, hidden_dim), minval=-k, maxval=k, dtype=np.float32), dtype=tf.float32)

objective = ...

nonnegativity = tf.nn.l2_loss(tf.nn.relu(tf.negative(self.W)))

loss = objective + 0.01*nonnegativity
self.train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)
```

I'm wondering if this is a correct way to implement such penalization.

Comment: Sure looks like a good solution to me.